# Do all node js versions use the same version of v8

Tags: node.js, v8

I noticed there was differences in how async calls were handled in the versions 8, 10 and 14.2 Node.js?

Did they update v8 in between causing those changes or am I hallucinating?

Comment: https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Dave Newton pointed out by linking to [nodejs.org/en/download/releases](https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases), Node.js regularly updates its V8 version.

V8 is under constant development, adding new JavaScript language features (like the `async` keyword), bug fixes, and performance improvements, and updating the V8 version used in Node is the way to let Node users benefit from these improvements.